# Почему не сортируется массив строк в структуре?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, сортировка

Проблема в том, что если строки имеют одинаковую длину, одна из строк уходит в конец таблицы, даже если она самая маленькая.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE 10

struct Processor {
string name;
float freq;
float ram;
char type;
};
struct Processor ob[SIZE];

void TabPrint(Processor *ob, int count) {
printf_s("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
cout << setw(45) << "Характристики ПЭВМ " << endl;
printf_s("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
cout << "|" << setw(16) << "Процессор" << "|" << setw(16) << "Частота(Mgz)" << "|" << setw(16) << "RAM(Mb)" << "|" << setw(16) << "Тип" << "|" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << "|" << setw(16) << ob[i].name << "|" << setw(16) << ob[i].freq << "|" << setw(16) << ob[i].ram << "|" << setw(16) << ob[i].type << "|" << endl;
}
printf_s("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
cout << "Тип: C-CISC-процессор, R-RISC-процессор" << endl;
printf_s("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main()
{
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int count = 0;
// заполнение таблицы
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout << i + 1 << ") Введите название просессора: ";
    cin >> ob[i].name;
    if (ob[i].name == "***") break;
    count++;
    cout << i + 1 << ") Введите частоту(Mgz): ";
    cin >> ob[i].freq;
    cout << i + 1 << ") Введите RAM(Mb): ";
    cin >> ob[i].ram;
    cout << i + 1 << ") Введите тип: ";
    cin >> ob[i].type;
}

TabPrint(ob, count);
// сортировка таблицы
struct Processor temp;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++) {
        if (ob[j].name > ob[j + 1].name) {
            temp = ob[j];
            ob[j] = ob[j + 1];
            ob[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

TabPrint(ob, count);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Вы наверное названия русскими буквами вводите. В кодировке `cp-1251` им соответствуют отрицательные коды (коды символов (`char`) более 127 при преобразовании для сравнения char в int станут отрицательными из-за распространения знакового разряда (бит 7 в 8-ми битном char))

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, пишите на C++ или на С. У вас какая то мешанина